# Poor Battery due to WiFI Intel 7260 Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, networking, power-management, battery

I am using a Lenovo T440 laptop, which has an Intel Dual Band Wireless-AC 7260 WiFi card. According to PowerTOP, the card is using about 9.5W power while the rest of the system uses less than a fifth of that combined. Wireless power saving is enabled. These readings are taken while I'm not downloading.

Is this a bug with PowerTOP, or could it be that the card is truly drawing this much power?

Thanks very much

[Screenshot of PowerTOP readings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V4SFT.png)

[Screenshot of iwconfig](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FBhQ6.png)

Comment: Powertop is wrong about power usage of single components. Just ignore the shown values.

Comment: @linrunner Could you please convert that to an answer so that schmucks like me who go around hunting for unanswered questions don't have to look at this one any more?  **;-)**  (And I'll upvote if you drop me a note and it's a good one too!)

Answer (score 0):

Powertop is wrong about power usage of single components. Just ignore the shown values.

Only the total power value is correct.

ps. for power saving use [TLP](http://linrunner.de/tlp).